# Can an service(nativescript-angular) be accessed within an IOS app delegate?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am trying to access an angular service from within IOS app delegate that is triggered by an system event, can i access the service if not what other options do we have??

Comment: It's not ideal to access an Angular service within app delegate. But instead you could fire an event from your app delegate on application module and listen to the same in a Angular component / service, just like how we work with application event like resume, pause etc.,

Comment: Thank you Manoj, was of great help.